# Sending data from serial port

Tags: python, serial-port, raspberry-pi2, zigbee

I would like to send one string over the serial port :

I have two raspberry pi 2. Each one have a xbee module. I want to send data from one to the other. They are correctly connected.

To test sending data I have this little python script :

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600, timeout=.5)
cpt = 0

while True:
    ser.write('{}'.format(cpt))
    ser.write(' Hello world ! \r\n')
    cpt = cpt + 1
```

My other raspberry pi connected with minicom recieves these data

```
 world !
8  Hello world !
9  Hello world !
10  Hello world !
11  Hello world !
12  Hello world !
13  Hello world !
14  Hello world !
15  Hello world !
...
```

The output is weird sometimes it begin at 10, sometimes at 5. In this output I have the word "world" which is alone ...

But i just want to send one string with this code :

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600, timeout=.5)

ser.write('Hello world ! \r\n')
```

Now I recieved nothing ... I don't know why.

Everyone know my problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Add a delay after opening the serial port before you start sending data to it.  It's possible that the XBee module doesn't power up before opening the serial port, and requires some time to boot up and reestablish a link to the other module.

At 9600 baud (roughly 960 cps), if you're losing 190 characters (10 sequences 0 to 9, each 19 characters including spaces and CRLF) you'd want a delay of roughly 190/960 = 0.2 seconds.  Bump it up to 0.5 seconds if you're not in a hurry, and see if that resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Some possibilities:

- Since it's not a continuous loop anymore, the connection to the other Pi should be persistent when you run the script on the first Pi. Are the connections persistent?
- Is the serial port ttyUSB0 correct? Check the serial port using dmesg.
- The connections may be loose, or the power supply to the Pi may be insufficient.

Please update if any of this works.